# How can a PIC18F4550 communicate with ROS?

Tags: ros, microcontroller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,
I am using a PIC18F4550 microcontroller for controlling a stepper motor and a regular dc motor through their drivers (H-bridges). I was wondering if anyone knows a simple way to make ROS communicate with the microcontroller.
I know that one way to do this is to buy an arduino chip and follow the tutorials on this website. Then write a simple code to make the arduino chip communicate with the PIC microcontroller. Unfortunately, due to budget limit and lack of time this is not possible.
I would be really greatfull if anyone could help me soon.

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35703/how-can-a-pic18f4550-communicate-with-ros?/) by [Engineer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2543/engineer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2012-06-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Two ways:

1. Implement the [rosserial](http://ros.org/wiki/rosserial) protocol on the PIC and use rosserial client to communicate with ROS. More generic and more work (you can probably reuse some code from rosserial_arduino).
2. Implement your own simple protocol and write a client nodes that maps this to ROS. Limited to what you implement, but quick to do.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2